# Python Unicode Print Error

Tags: python, unicode

Doing some unicode testing and have encountered an error that I have not been able to overcome.

```
# -- coding: utf-8 -- Enable direct Unicade-8 encoding
    # Imports #
from __future__ import print_function
import locale
from unicodedata import *

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') # Set the locale for your system 'en_US.UTF-8'

def main():
    xlist=[]
    for i in range(9729, 9731):
        xlist.append(eval('u"\\u{:04x}"'.format(i)))
    for x in xlist:
        #print(name(u' ','-'))
        if name(x,'-')!='-':
            #print("{} | {:04x} | {}".format(x, ord(x), name(x,'-'))) #1

            print( x,'|', "%04x"%(ord(x)), '|', name(x,'-')) #2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That runs fine. But when I change to trying to print using the print line labeled #1 instead of number #2, I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2601' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have researched the error, but it seems to be with my formatting. However, the formatting is the same, or very similar, in #1 as in #2.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using `unichr()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert formatting pattern into uniode string.

```
print(u"{} | {:04x} | {}".format(x, ord(x), name(x,'-')))
```

Comment: That was the ticket. You the dude. Thanks.